# How to find 2 characters near each other using Regex

Tags: regex, xcode

I want to find in my project all of the below:

> %f
>
> %4f
>
> %.5f

So basically how to find all cases where we have % and f with something in-between, how is that done?

Comment: Is this to find usage in `sprintf`? If this is the case,the current answers are not complete.

Comment: Yeah is for printf

Comment: C++ or php? (the options are not the same)

Comment: Is for Xcode finder global search, I bet is C++ or C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find floating point formats for `printf` in xcode according to https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html the following would be a complete regex :

```
%(\d+$)?[#0+- ']*\d*(\.\d+)?[lL]?f
```

`(\d+$)?` the value selector, `[#0+- ']*` the flags, `\d*` the width, `(\.\d+)?`, the precision and `[lL]?` the width modifier

Comment: whoa, this maybe the winner

Comment: it says %(\d+$)?[#0+- ']*\d*\.?\d*[lL]?f is not a valid Reg Ex

Comment: %(\d+$)?(#0+- ')*\d*\.?\d*(lL)?f

Comment: This one even found %10.2f

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't define that just a certain amount of characters should be inbetween you could just use `%.*f`

For two characters in between use something like
`%(.){2}f` 
For 0-2 characters in between use something like:
`%[.][.]f`

Possibly useful resources:

- [different regex standards](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)
- [character classes shorthands](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refshorthand.html)
- [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)

Comment: The other guy gave a better one seems like

Comment: It's more specific on the 3 samples you provided, I used a more general pattern, so just accept which the one more appealing to you :)

Answer (score 1):

A pattern better suited to your examples is: `%\.?\d*f`

Note that **unquoted** `.` in a pattern means **any char** (not just a dot).

In my pattern the dot is **optional**, so I put a `?` after it.

Then there can be an optional **sequence of digits** (not any chars),
so I put `\d*`.

The last part is literal `f`.